# Import maketrans

Tags: python, string, import, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying import a built-in string (maketrans) on Jupyter Notebook.

```
from string import maketrans
```

An error pops up:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'maketrans' from 'string' 
(.../anaconda3/lib/python3.8/string.py)
```

Is the - from import - the right way?

I checked the file for "maketrans" but couldn't find anything.
is there anyway to manually add these kind of strings?

Comment: you needn't import. ref: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/maketrans

Comment: maketrans('ABCDEF','NOPQRS'). This is not working. Is this single line syntax correct?

Comment: `string.maketrans(firstString, secondString)` * don't forget `string.`